# What does "tr[class^="row"]" mean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What does this `^` mean in the following code line:

```
tr[class^="row"]
```

In the HTML how does it looks like? if used:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr[class^="row"]');
```

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's not jquery, it's just css selectors in general.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @PeterSmith that's not jQuery ...

Comment: [A jsfiddle for you to look at](https://jsfiddle.net/v1dw8qqd/).

Comment: @Damon - yes, look at too quickly - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a css selector, `^=` means "begins with"

Please see [MDN - Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more information.

Comment: That is right, so why downvoting?